# Running count of the number of missing values with reset?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an indicator column `cond`. I want to create a new column that equals `-1` if anytime before `cond == T`, `0` if `cond == T`, and counts the number of rows until `cond` is true again.

What I am looking for is something conceptually similar to the `cumsum(is.na(tmp))` that restarts after every 0.

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(cond = c(F, F, T, T, F, T, F, F, F, F, T)) %>% 
  mutate(tmp = case_when(cumsum(cond) == 0 ~ -1,
                         cond ~ 0,
                         T ~ NA_real_))
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    cond    tmp
#>    <lgl> <dbl>
#>  1 FALSE    -1
#>  2 FALSE    -1
#>  3 TRUE      0
#>  4 TRUE      0
#>  5 FALSE    NA
#>  6 TRUE      0
#>  7 FALSE    NA
#>  8 FALSE    NA
#>  9 FALSE    NA
#> 10 FALSE    NA
#> 11 TRUE      0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Desired output:

```r
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    cond    tmp
#>    <lgl> <dbl>
#>  1 FALSE    -1
#>  2 FALSE    -1
#>  3 TRUE      0
#>  4 TRUE      0
#>  5 FALSE     1
#>  6 TRUE      0
#>  7 FALSE     1
#>  8 FALSE     2
#>  9 FALSE     3
#> 10 FALSE     4
#> 11 TRUE      0
```

Comment: i want to fill the NA's in the `tmp` with a running count that resets after every 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rleid` to create a grouping column and then replace the 'tmp' `if` `all` the values are `NA` with the sequence (`row_number()`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat <- dat %>% 
    group_by(grp = rleid(is.na(tmp))) %>% 
    mutate(tmp = if(all(is.na(tmp))) row_number() else tmp) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

-output

```
dat
# A tibble: 11 × 2
   cond    tmp
   <lgl> <dbl>
 1 FALSE    -1
 2 FALSE    -1
 3 TRUE      0
 4 TRUE      0
 5 FALSE     1
 6 TRUE      0
 7 FALSE     1
 8 FALSE     2
 9 FALSE     3
10 FALSE     4
11 TRUE      0
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(cond = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), tmp = c(-1, -1, 0, 0, NA, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Ah very close, but I want the value to reset after every 0

Comment: see the Desired output edit

Comment: @John-Henry sorry, i didn't see the values properly earlier.  Updated the post